# Laravel FormRequest get input value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to use FormRequest:

```
class RegistrationForm extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required|confirmed'
        ];
    }

    public  function persist(){
        $user=new User();
        $user->name=$this->only(['name']);
        $user->email=$this->only(['email']);
        dd($this->only(['password']);
        auth()->login($user);
    }
}
```

I need get in persist()  method inputs value from my requst. I tried to get 'password' value, but I got array. 
How can I get input value like a string?

Comment: kinda late, but as `FormRequest extends Request` so you can use `$this->input_name`

Answer (score 10):

You can get the values using the `input()` function:

```
public function persist() {
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $this->input('name');
    $user->email = $this->input('email');
    dd($this->input('password'));
    auth()->login($user);
}
```

Ps: I suggest you do your logic in the controller not in the request class.

Comment: This is useful when we need ignore a unique rule on update one database data..

Like this: 

`Rule::unique('tab')->ignore($this->input('id_field'), 'id_field')`

Answer (score 2):

Form request classes extend the Request class, so you can refer to the current request (and any methods) using $this, i.e.
$this->input('password').

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_get` method.

```
$value = array_get($your_array, 'key_name');
```

**PS**: `array_get` accepts a third argument, which is returned when given key is not found in the give array.

Answer (score -1):

According to documentation FormRequest::only will return array type data. You need to extract value from that array.

[FormRequest::only](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html#method_only)